# Delete record with attr ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to delete via `<li id='{$row['id']}'>` It works but fails to delete the record from mysql only deletes it front end. Is it possible to delete via defining the ID with `attr`? Here is my current code:

PHP, (works fine and deletes multiple fields)

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM img_nav WHERE id = :id";
$sql = "DELETE FROM img_landing WHERE id = :id";
$sql = "DELETE FROM img_slider WHERE id = :id";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);   
$stmt->execute();
```

My jQuery/Ajax

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  $(".deleteitem").click(function(){

    var parent = $(this).closest('li');
    var id = parent.attr('id');

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "id=" +id,
      URL: "delete.php",
      success: function(){
        $('#'+id).remove();
      }
    });
  });
});
```

The HTML markup, I echo the content with PHP/PDO:

```
<li id='{$row['id']}'>
<div class='imgHover'>
<div class='hover'>
<a href='#' ><img src='../img/delete.png'></a></div><img src='{$row['path']}'>
</div></li>
```

When linking directly to `delete.php` I have no problems it works fine, it's just sending the ID with ajax that is the issue. Could it be an issue with MAMP? I have not tested remotely.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with how you're retrieving the data on the server.

```
type: "POST"
```

Is what you indicate in your AJAX call, but on the server you do

```
$id = (int) $_GET['id'];
```

So you're never capturing the post. Change `$_GET[]` to `$_POST[]`.

**Note**

Just a small note, if you typecast that to `(int)`, and you send a fraction/float, it will round towards 0, not up. so `3.57` as `(int)` will be `3`

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have made those amendments yet still having no luck, I deleted (int) too. Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @User_coder Navigate directly to the page `delete.php?id=10`, do a `echo '<pre>', print_r($_POST, true), '</pre>'; exit();` Then see what the results of the dump are. If all works correcly, check the path to `delete.php` to make sure it's resolving to the right location.

Comment: I am getting a blank `Array ()` must not be recognising my ID. Thanks for your time again. I am trying to troubleshoot this. still don't know where I am going wrong...

Comment: @User_coder or you simply do `$_REQUEST[]` which will identify both `$_GET` and `$_POST`, just like Killer Whale said above my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know you should use $_GET or $_POST, you can use $_REQUEST. But do you think there is any problem with this query $sql = "DELETE FROM img_nav WHERE id = :id"; and so on? Does program know what is this? You should try $sql = "DELETE FROM img_nav WHERE id = '{$id}'"; I think it works.